# is it possible to launch a browser with URL when plugging a USB device into an android phone?

Tags: android, usb, device

i want to open a specific URL when my USB device is plugged into an android phone. (this URL will point to the play store or some other location to download the application needed for this USB device).

The USB device can not be a AOA accessory as it can not supply power nor having a USB host capabilities.

thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is for solving problems with existing code, not writing code. Please do some research/attempt.

Comment: well, so far i have implemented a USB device (MSD / CDC/ HID) on my STM32F0 board. communicated with it with an android phone. i also did some google research, found how to launch and application on iphone, as well as on android with open accessory protocol. however i can not find how to do it when the accessory is a device.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to launch the url page on the host pc then this helps a lot https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html , that is a tutorial of working with usb , listening for new devices... if you want to launch the url on the android device follow this [USB Connection notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522963/usb-connection-notification)

Comment: thanks, but i am looking for launching an app (or open a URL) without pre-writing anything to the android device,

Comment: you want to lauch the app on the pc or on the android device ?

Comment: on the android device

Comment: actuallyi can't find a way to ask a device to do a task without writing a peogram , you are asking to start a webpage on the device without installing anything on it  ?

Comment: yes, something like the disk contents shown when a USB flash is connected.

Comment: what you can do , is installing a application that starts when a usb is branched from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172611/android-broadcastreceiver-when-insert-remove-the-device-usb-plug-into-from-a-us